# Why does the new review page sometimes shows questions to vote to close without anybody having voted to close it?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

I was reviewing [close votes](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/143547) for [table layout textview allignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11465371/table-layout-textview-allignment), and noticed that nobody voted to close it, even though the page reports a duplicate.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lower reputation users ([< 3k](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions)) cannot vote to close, but they *can* flag posts for moderator attention, which includes a 'Duplicate' option.

I bet you a thousand reputation points that the post in question was flagged in that manner.

This is what it looks like for a lower rep user (like me, here on SO):

[image: Flagging your question; I cancelled, no need to worry!]

Note that it looks identical to the 'vote to close' dialog, but instead I'm informing the moderators here. It makes perfect sense to have the wider community review these to help out.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it's even a specific option while flagging. Doesn't that open the flood gates for moderators?

Comment: As 5k user, I don't see when somebody flags a question. If the new review page allows me to see when somebody flags a question as duplicate, that is really good.

Comment: @Arjan Users who cannot vote to close can flag the question as "it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate." That is not something new, and you can do it too (except that the dialog box would be the voting to close one, in your case). What is new is that users who are not 10k users are informed that somebody flagged a question to close it.

Comment: I understand, @kiamlaluno, and I think that is good. Sorry I was not very clear in my comment. I meant to say that leaving those kinds of flags for moderators (well, until now), while I would guess there are plenty of community members who can deal with it, surprised me. I'd have expected that people would just leave a comment, rather than flag. (But then: I don't hear the moderators complain about it, so I'm fine with it too, of course.)